# Erro ao tentar gera apk ionic v2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ionic, ionic2

> Comando:

```
 ionic build android --prod
```

Variáveis de ambiente:

> ANDROID_HOME

```
C:\Android\sdk
```

> CLASSPATH

```
.;%JAVA_HOME%
```

> JAVA_HOME

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
```

> Path

```
;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

> Erro:

```
Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Andorid SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: C:\Users\Octávio Barbosa\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Se tiver o android studio instalado abre o projecto com ele, ai ele mesmo ja resolve essas coisas (normalmente)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde amigo,

Também tive esse problema com o IONIC2, acho que você tem que configurar as seguintes ***variáveis de sistema*** configuradas:

**JAVA_HOME**: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65 ***(Local do seu JDK)***

**ANDROID_HOME**: C:\programas\android-sdk-eclipse-adt-m4\sdk ***(Local onde está o SDK do android)***

No seu PATH, vc vai que juntar com os caminhos que ja existem

**PATH**: C:\Program Files\nodejs\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;

**Observação**: na variavel do path, colocada acima, estou concatenando os caminhos do node, java e do android tools e platform